# How can I make different folders from different projects with gulp?

Tags: javascript, html, gulp

I have this structure:

```
app:
---Project A
 --subfolder
  -index.html
---Project B
 --subfolder
  -index.html
---Project C
 --subfolder
  -index.html
--Styles
--Scripts
dist: As a result I want
--Project A
--subfolder
  -index.html
--Project B
--subfolder
 -index.html
--Project C
--subfolder
-index.html
--Styles
--Scripts
```

This is my code so far:

```
gulp.task('html', () => {
  return gulp.src([
      'app/index.html',
      'app/nl/**/index.html', //gets only one site
      'app/com/**/index.html', //gets only one site
      '!app/landing/styles/**/*.html',
      '!app/bower_components/**/*.html'
    ])
    .pipe($.useref({ searchPath: '{.tmp,app}' }))
    // Remove any unused CSS
    .pipe($.if('*.css', $.uncss({
      html: [ 'app/index.html' ],
      // CSS Selectors for UnCSS to ignore
      ignore: []
    })))
    // Concatenate and minify styles
    // In case you are still using useref build blocks
    .pipe($.if('*.css', $.cssnano()))
    // Minify any HTML
    .pipe($.if('*.html', $.minifyHtml()))
    .pipe($.if('*.html', $.minifyInline({
      js: { output: { comments: false } },
      jsSelector: 'script[type!="text/x-handlebars-template"]',
      css: { keepSpecialComments: 1 },
      cssSelector: 'style[data-do-not-minify!="true"]'
    })))
    // Output files
    .pipe($.if('*.html', $.size({ title: 'html', showFiles: true })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

I'm only able to get the subfolder and the index.html. However when I'm able to get the all the folders I need I get conflicts with the scripts inside the html and the scripts that are inside the gulp.file

Answer (score 0):

The solution could be passing a function to **gulp.dest** in order to tell him in which folder need to write the file. Try that:

```
gulp.task('html', () => {
  return gulp.src([
      'app/index.html',
      'app/nl/**/index.html', //gets only one site
      'app/com/**/index.html', //gets only one site
      '!app/landing/styles/**/*.html',
      '!app/bower_components/**/*.html'
    ])
    .pipe($.useref({ searchPath: '{.tmp,app}' }))
    // Remove any unused CSS
    .pipe($.if('*.css', $.uncss({
      html: [ 'app/index.html' ],
      // CSS Selectors for UnCSS to ignore
      ignore: []
    })))
    // Concatenate and minify styles
    // In case you are still using useref build blocks
    .pipe($.if('*.css', $.cssnano()))
    // Minify any HTML
    .pipe($.if('*.html', $.minifyHtml()))
    .pipe($.if('*.html', $.minifyInline({
      js: { output: { comments: false } },
      jsSelector: 'script[type!="text/x-handlebars-template"]',
      css: { keepSpecialComments: 1 },
      cssSelector: 'style[data-do-not-minify!="true"]'
    })))
    // Output files
    .pipe($.if('*.html', $.size({ title: 'html', showFiles: true })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest((file) => {
      //You can see which file is treated here.
      //Then you return a String with the destination of the file.
    }));
});
```

It's not a full answer, but I think at least could give you a trace to follow.